# Garrys Mod Lua problem (check equal and print)

Tags: lua, equals, garrys-mod

I don't have any errors.
My scrips can take the name of new weapon but it cant check equal of hololink_swep.
The print of equal doesn't appear.
Please help.

My code:

```
hook.Add( "PlayerSwitchWeapon", function( ply, oldWeapon, newWeapon )
    print( "Your new weapon is " .. newWeapon:GetClass() .. "." );
        if ( newWeapon == hololink_swep ) then
            print( "This weapon is speciall" .. newWeapon:GetClass() .. "." );
        end
end );
```

Comment: is `hololink_swep` intended to be the actual value that your are checking or a variable that holds the value? if it is the actual value then you need to add `"` around it. i.e. `"hololink_swep"`

Answer (score 0):

if (tostring(newWeapon) == tostring(hololink_swep) )

Answer (score 0):

```
    hook.Add("PlayerSwitchWeapon", "some name of hook", function(ply, oldWeapon, newWeapon)
        print("Your new weapon is " .. newWeapon:GetClass() .. ".")
        if (newWeapon == "hololink_swep") then
            print("This weapon is speciall" .. newWeapon:GetClass() .. ".")
        end
    end)
```

also do not forget to name your hook. I named it for example `some name of hook`.

Comment: Thank you for responde but i still doesnt have the print of speciall weapon.